# Python-Unable to locate CSS class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script to collect weather data from a webpage. My code goes as follows:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# open the webpage and assign the content to a new variable
base = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Washington+DC+20006:4:US')
f = base.readlines()
f = str(f)


soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

rn_base = soup.find(itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit")
right_now = rn_base.string
print(right_now)

fl_base = soup.find(itemprop="feels-like-temperature-fahrenheit")
feels_like = fl_base.string
print(feels_like)

td_base = soup.find_all('class_="wx-temperature"')
print(td_base)
```

So `right_now` and `feels_like` print fine, but when it comes to `td_base`, it returns either `None` or `[]`, an empty list depending on whether using `.find` or `.find_all`. To paraphrase in regards to the HTML source code, my code is able to locate `itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit"` and `itemprop="feels-like-temperature-fahrenheit"`, but fails on `class_="wx-temperature"`. I'd appreciate any thoughts about why the first two would succeed but not the third one. Thank you!

P.S.: Here is an excerpt of the html source code that is relevant(IMO) to the task at hand:

```
<div class="wx-data-part wx-first">
<div class="wx-temperature"><span itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit">87</span><span class="wx-degrees">&deg;<span class="wx-unit">F</span></span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">FEELS LIKE
<span itemprop="feels-like-temperature-fahrenheit">93</span>&deg;</div>
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<div class="wx-temperature">94<span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">HIGH AT 3:25 PM</div>
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<div class="wx-temperature">76<span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">LOW</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove surrounding `'`:

```
td_base = soup.find_all(class_="wx-temperature")
```